Batchfile problem processing 2 different filenames in loop at same time
I want to make a batch file, (Windows 10), to combine different tracks from 2 video files using mkvmerge!
I want to automate this using a loop so that all files in two different directories are processed. The number of files is the same in both directories, and they are both correctly sorted.
for example:
files für videos1 in directory 1files for videos2 in directory 2.
finished Files in directory joined.A loop if the file names in directories 1 and 2 match, is no problem:
for %%f in (1/*.mkv) do (
    mkvmerge --output "joined/%%f" --no-audio --no-subtitles "1/%%f" --no-video --no-chapters --no-global-tags --no-attachments "2/%%f"
)

Unfortunately the file names are not the same and now I have the question how to change the script here when the filnames are different?
This is what the automatic processing should look like:
1\1safrsrffm & 2\file1fgdfgtr -> finished\1safrsrffm
1\2dfsdffdd & 2\file2fdewrrh -> finished/2dfsdffdd
1\3dffdsfffm & 2\file3fgfdggf -> finished\3dffdsfffm
1\4dfggggg & 2\file4dgfgdgf -> finished\4dfggggg

This site does not offer a free code writing service. If you have a task to perform, the onus is upon you to research and write your own code for that task. Here we help you to fix an issue with code written for the intended task, but which fails to achieve it as expected.

So simple, as I outlined in your question when it was in Staging Ground:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "dir1=u:\your files"
SET "dir2=u:\your results"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%u IN (' dir /s /b "%dir1%\*.mkv" ^|findstr /n "." ') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%U IN (' dir /s /b "%dir2%\*.mkv" ^|findstr /n "." ') DO (
  IF "%%u"=="%%U" ECHO merge "%%v" with "%%V" giving "%%~nv"
 )
)
GOTO :EOF


Great, thank You!
